# Tabularx or Tabulary populated by csvsimple

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary, csvsimple

I am using `csvsimple` to import table data.

Some cell information is too long and I would like to dynamically manage the column width. I have tried combining the `tabularx` and `tabulary` environments with the `csvsimple` part, but I have been unsuccessful. I am using the `memoir` document class.

Here is my fixed-width code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,letterpaper, openleft, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,csvsimple,longtable}
...
%Type of column
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{#1\hspace{0pt}\arraybackslash}p{75pt}}
...
\begin{document}
...
\csvreader[tabular={P{\raggedright}P{\raggedright}P{\raggedright}P{\raggedright}P{\raggedright}}, %
head to column names=true, %
table head=\hline \textbf{Short header} & \textbf{Middle header} & %
\textbf{middle header} & \textbf{long text header} & \textbf{long text header}\\\hline, %
table foot=\hline, filter equal={\csvcoli}{Something}]{mycsv.csv}%
{}%
{\csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi}\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you are out of luck, unless Thomas makes a major upgrade.

Comment: You can try [`pgfplotstable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) which can use `tabularx` (IIRC). Can you please complete your example to include `\documentclass{}` and `\end{document}`? Thanks!

Comment: darthbith : Change done for the exemple; Would it be possible threw an other way? without tabularx or tabulary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be difficult to integrate `tabularx` into the option list of the macro `\csvreader`; for an environment, there would be ways.

But you can always put a `tabularx` environment around a `\csvreader`. The following example shows, how to do this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mycsv.csv}
This,is,my,example
Red,Green,This is some very very long text,This is also some very very long text
Blue,Yellow,This is some even longer text without real content,This is also some even longer text without real content
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[pdftex,10pt,letterpaper, openleft, twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,csvsimple,longtable,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{llXX}\toprule
\textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}\\\midrule
\csvreader[late after line=\\\midrule,late after last line=\\\bottomrule]
  {mycsv.csv}
  {}
  {\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much again, it worked perfectly. Would it work with tabulary also ?(I suppose yes)

Comment: @SimonBoucher Yes, [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238253/tabular-changing-column-separator/238283#238283) is an example of using it with tabulary.

Comment: To make the table span over multiple pages it is possible to use `\usepackage{ltablex}`, which union the advantages of `tabularx` and `longtable`. In the actuall table there is no change required, it happens automatically.