# tabular - changing column separator

Tags: tables

Is it possible to change default column separator character (&) for tabular environment ? I find it convenient to edit content of table in LibreOffice Calc and save it as csv file. This csv file I include in tex code like this:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{6}{L}}
        \toprule
        \input{data.csv}
    \end{tabulary} \hfill \
\end{table}
```

It is possible to change column separator when first saving csv file so this is not problem. But when opening already created csv file, editing it and saving, LibreOffice without asking uses default column separator which is semicolon (;) and rewrites previous separator (&). So for me it would be better to switch latex to using semicolon as column separator character instead of ampersand.

Comment: You can use [`pgfplotstable`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplotstable) which comes with `pgfplots`.

Comment: `\catcode\`\;=4`

Comment: what is `\hfill \ ` doing here?

Comment: @David: "\hfil \" align table to the left instead of centering it.

Comment: Left align is the default, and the table is full width so `..} \hfill\ ` just makes a spurious white line under the table looking like `\vspace{\baselineskip}`

Comment: @David: In my case table is horizontally centered in text body by default.

Comment: That is why the example in your question should always be a complete document not a fragment. But `\hfill\ ` is incorrect in any case, why force a word space?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
11.0; 12.3; one; two
1.2; 33.11; five; six
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\catcode`\;=4
\catcode`\^^M=13 %
\def^^M{\\}%
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}%
        \toprule%
        \input{data.csv}%
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution which is simple and clean, but unfortunately in real-world document it doesnt function. It generates tons of errors like for example "! Missing number, treated as zero." or "! Missing $ inserted." on line with `\catcode`\^^M=13. Its hard to extract essence of problem into small MWE because there are interdependencies between various commands which I am unable to comprehend without some debugging tools.

Comment: @truthseeker did you forget the `\`` before `\^^M` ? that would make a missing `$` error.

Comment: No, I copy-pasted it.

Comment: @truthseeker well something else is wrong then:-)

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `cvssimple`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
11.0; 12.3; one; two
1.2; 33.11; five; six
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{*{4}{L}}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\midrule
\csvreader[
  separator=semicolon,
  no head,
  late after line=\\,
]{\jobname.csv}{}{%
  \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv
}
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}

\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is my alternative using datatool.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
11.0; 12.3; one; two
1.2; 33.11; five; six
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}
\DTLsetseparator{;}
\DTLloadrawdb[noheader,keys={ca,cb,cc,cd}]{ctext}{data.csv}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{l}}%
        \toprule%
    \DTLforeach{ctext}{\ca=ca, \cb=cb, \cc=cc,\cd=cd}%
        {%
        \DTLiffirstrow{}%
            {%
            \\%
            }%
            \ca&%
            \cb&%
            \cc&%
            \cd%
        }%
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Its more generic because you can fully seperate design and content.